# Reusing ActiveMQ for Camel JMS Endpoints

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

We currently use activemq for JMS within Camel. Now our requirements have mandated us to create a completely separate application (separate jvm instance) that also uses ActiveMQ Standalone to broker messages with external clients.

I want to know if we can use this separate standalone for the camel jms endpoints Or if it is possible to use the embedded activemq in camel for our new separate application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single ActiveMQ instance. Just make sure you have no destination name collisions [unless they will share] and that your instance creates networked listeners using **tcp://** or one of the other networked protocols, i.e. you would not want to use **vm://**.

Comment: I just rejigged the Camel app so the new process starts the embedded activeMQ and it works just as you said. I actually declared both Vm and tcp using the broker definition in Spring and it worked. tx